# How to install specific older version of Deluge with all the dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, bittorrent, 19.10, deluge

I have deluged 1.3.15 running on Raspberry Pi. However, I'm running eoan and it comes with Deluge 2.0.3. Version 2 client isn't backward compatible with version 1 server, so I need to install Deluge 1.3.15.

From what I can tell, it isn't in the repo, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it installed otherwise. I tried downloading old disco binaries but there is a myriad of unmet dependencies which I'm not sure how to satisfy.

How can I get Deluge 1.3.15 running so I can connect to deluged?

Comment: I have exactly the same settings, and hence the same problem, but in Ubuntu 20.04, for which the given solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Original method for Ubuntu 19.10

You can simply install [packages from *disco*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/disco/deluge) on your *eoan* system with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-common_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-gtk_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge_1.3.15-2_all.deb
sudo apt install ./deluge*.deb
```

and then lock their versions with single long command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-deluge
Package: deluge
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-common
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-gtk
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

and enjoy:

> ```
> $ deluge --version
> deluge: 1.3.15
> libtorrent: 1.1.13.0
> ```

---

### Updated method for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

You can simply install [packages from *bionic*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/deluge) on your *focal* system with

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/deluge
cd ~/Downloads/deluge
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libt/libtorrent-rasterbar/python-libtorrent_1.1.5-1build1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libt/libtorrent-rasterbar/libtorrent-rasterbar9_1.1.5-1build1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.65.1/libboost-system1.65.1_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/boost1.65.1/libboost-python1.65.1_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-common_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/twisted/python-twisted-core_17.9.0-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/twisted/python-twisted-bin_17.9.0-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/incremental/python-incremental_16.10.1-3_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/notify-python/python-notify_0.1.1-4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-common_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-gtk_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge_1.3.15-2_all.deb

sudo apt install ./*.deb
```

and then lock their versions with single long command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-deluge
Package: deluge
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-common
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-gtk
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libtorrent-rasterbar9
Pin: version 1.1.5-1build1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

and enjoy:

> ```
> $ deluge --version
> deluge: 1.3.15
> libtorrent: 1.1.5.0
> ```

Comment: I followed these steps, but annoyingly, deluge kept updating along with normal apt updates. To prevent this, I used:
`sudo apt-mark hold deluge`

Comment: THANK YOU - Works on Linux Mint 20 too .

Comment: OP: what is really good is when there is a comment by another user, and there should be some dialogue about the suggestion with the other user, and if the suggestion is accepted that it is added to the original answer to help improve the answer.
If it is not acceptable, it is debated to at least rule the suggestion out.
Because the rest of us that don't know better, we come here and are left wondering what it the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks N0rbert!
I have follow your instructions with a slight modification, all I installed was:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-common_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-gtk_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge_1.3.15-2_all.deb
```

Then locked the update up with:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-deluge
Package: deluge
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-common
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-gtk
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libtorrent-rasterbar9
Pin: version 1.1.5-1build1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

**The above answers are good they deserve the credit I would have updated them with my info here but maybe that is incorrect, I do not want to break their good work.**

My use case is a deluged service running with a deluge-gtk watching that service.
I was getting high ram usage due to the ubuntu upgrade 20.4, and the impending upgrade of deluge to 2.0.3+

Also I upgraded libtorrent, that was a nightmare which completely broke everything.
So this 1.3.15 works better for me on Ubuntu 20.4
It also required a lot of removing of lots of applications, but be warned I removed too much and it caused masses of issues.

I was lost due to the various solutions out there on web, that cause all kinds of problems.

**If it wasn't for the above answers, I would still be lost.**

I followed the above instructions but added deluged / deluge-web / deluge-console

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-web_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluged_1.3.15-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deluge/deluge-console_1.3.15-2_all.deb
```

changes to this command

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-deluge
Package: deluge
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-common
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-gtk
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluged
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-console
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: deluge-web
Pin: version 1.3.15-2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libtorrent-rasterbar9
Pin: version 1.1.5-1build1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```